# buttons(and other views) after change on new resolution

Tags: android, button

I now writing app. App was tested on emulator with 320x480 resolution. There i see all ok. After i tried run this app on emulator with 480x800 resolution and saw this problem. I can't understand why this happened. Can any explain me or help to fix this.

[image: bad buttons]

[image: good buttons]

Please, tell me how to fix this.
im programming **without xml** only code

code for button to layout :

```
bottomL.addView(myButton);
```

Regards,Peter

**SOLVED** need use dip(dpi) instead px

Comment: what is the height & width of both button in xml? and show your xml file.

Comment: post the xml from your layout

Comment: If you are giving the fix height to your layout containing both buttons it may be change your view and doesn't showing full height of their child view.

Answer (score 1):

either not setting width and height fixed, instead using wrap_content, and you can see supporting multiple screen resolutions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html